# How can I make !{ } in SparkViewEngine not render anything?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

How can I prevent the Spark view engine from rendering the debugging hint when a null ref exception is thrown in `!{ }`? It always renders "${ expression.that.throws.nre }". The [documentation](http://sparkviewengine.com/documentation/expressions) states that it should render an empty string... it never mentions the behavior I'm experiencing. Using `settings.SetDebug(false)` doesn't change this behavior, nor does setting the project to "Release".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$!{...}` usually does the trick.

`${...}` renders `${...}` if null ref exception was faced.

Are you sure you wrote `$!{}` and not `${}` or `!{}`?

Comment: Ha, wow. I somehow mentally filtered out the preceding '$' every time I scanned through that page. Thanks for pointing that out :). In that case, what does !{} do?

Comment: No ideas what `!{}` does. If it does anything at all. :)